# Cordova missing cordova_plugins.json file. Have added it but still getting error

Tags: json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have just started a Cordova/Phonegap 2.0.7 project. All is going well but when I test in a browser I get the message:

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/~~~/www/cordova_plugins.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. cordova-2.7.0.js:6410
```

I searched SO and found that this is a common bug and to just add a blank file name `cordova_plugins.json` to the `www` folder. I have done this but the error persists.

On top of this I also get a Failed to Load resource error for a file

`file://localhost/!gap_exec?1368772098759`

and I have no idea what it is.

I have not added any plugins to the project yet but am retrieving data via JSON with a small JQuery script. I am also using JQuery Mobile.

Would anyone know how to remedy this at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this from a local webserver?

Comment: @Geeniewanted just from my PC

Comment: I think I had to create the JSON file and add a {} inside it, eg, an empty JSON object. Not sure what the Failed to Load error is...

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/pull/25